# use Java Monitor instead of Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two methods, `request()` and `release()`, each thread that access `request()` must take control until it call `release()`, it means that no other thread will enter the request method until the current thread hasn't finished.
I need to implement this behavior with both the java monitor and the semaphores.
This is the class of the thread:

```
public class Process implements Runnable
{
private Thread thread;
private final int ID;
private Resource g;
private final int MIN = 1000, MAX = 5000;

private void delay()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep( (int) Math.random() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN); 
    } catch( InterruptedException ex){}
}

public Process(int ID, Resource g)
{
    this.thread = new Thread(this, "P#" + ID);
    this.ID = ID;
    this.g = g;
}

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        g.request(ID);
        delay();
        g.release();
        delay();
    }
}// run

public void start()
{
    this.thread.start();
}
}
```

Using the Semaphores it's easy to implement this behavior, I take the mutex in the `request()` method and release it in the `release()` method:

```
public class ResourceS implements Resource
{

private Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);

public void request(int ID) 
{
    try
    {
        mutex.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){}
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enter");
}

public void release()
{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " exit");
    mutex.release();
}

}
```

In a main I launch five thread, here is the output:

```
P#0 enter
P#0 exit
P#1 enter
P#1 exit
P#2 enter
P#2 exit
P#3 enter
P#3 exit
P#4 enter
P#4 exit
P#0 enter
P#0 exit
P#1 enter
P#1 exit
P#2 enter
P#2 exit
P#3 enter
```

As you can see it is correct, because each thread enter only when another has exited.
Using the monitor there is a problem, here is the code:

```
public class ResourceMonitor implements Resource
{
private Object lock = new Object();
private boolean oneInside = false;

public void request(int ID)
{
    synchronized (lock)
    {
        while(oneInside)
        {
            try { lock.wait(); } catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enter");
        oneInside = true;
    }
}

public void release()
{
    synchronized(lock)
    {
        if (oneInside)
        {
            lock.notifyAll();
            oneInside = false;
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " exit");
    }
}
}
```

This is the output using the monitor.

```
P#0 enter
P#0 exit
P#4 enter
P#4 exit
P#0 enter
P#0 exit
P#4 enter
P#4 exit
P#0 enter
P#0 exit
P#4 enter
P#4 exit
```

Only two threads enter and exit, sometimes instead of `P#4` is `P#1`. Do you know what is happening, and how to get the same ouptut I'm having using the semaphores?

Here is the code of the main for those who want to test it:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Resource g = new ResourceS();

    Process p0 = new Process(0, g);
    Process p1 = new Process(1, g);
    Process p2 = new Process(2, g);
    Process p3 = new Process(3, g);
    Process p4 = new Process(4, g);

    p0.start();
    p1.start();
    p2.start();
    p3.start();
    p4.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger to see what the other threads are doing? (In Eclipse I'd start the program in a debugger, then wait for a couple of iterations to make sure the threads are actually stuck, then pause the program and look at each thread separately)

Comment: The `synchronized` keyword does not implement a monitor. Sadly.

Comment: @immibis using the debugger the code works as intended, maybe there is some sort of starvation going on when the code runs normally. It could be that between all the threads in the queue only two of them get access to the critical section.

Comment: I would usually go with starvation too, but 1second wait time should be more than enough to guarantee that even unfair scheduling shouldn't be a problem. Code looks alright.

Comment: It looks like you are at the mercy of a greedy thread scheduler. When I run your code on Linux I get the result you get. When I run it on Windows I get all threads getting their turn.

Comment: @markbernard But there's a 1-5 second sleep between trying to acquire locks if I'm not completely wrong. That's really weird.

Comment: It is. The only way I could get all threads to run was to add a `Thread.sleep(5000)` at the end of the release method call, outside of the synchronized block.

Comment: @markbernard very interesting, I'm running it on OS X, I'll try it on windows too. Voo you're not wrong, that sleep time should let the others thread gain access to the lock. The native monitor of Java are unfair, while the semaphores are fair, this could be the source of the problem. I'll try with an implementation of an Hoare monitor which should have a fair behavior

Comment: Yep, the sleep *outside* the lock obviously has to be *longer* than the one inside (overlooked that one), otherwise due to the unfair scheduling we get the given behavior. Otherwise yes you'll need something that gives fair scheduling behavior.

Comment: `while(true)` is a **very** bad programming choice, this app will deadlock at some point, no matter how many `break` statements you might use. Also : you are not using a `mutex`, you're using a `Semaphore` - these are two completely different things although semaphores can **imitate** the functionality of mutexes - but if you use semaphores like mutexes you're most likely doing something wrong. Just sayan.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening:

- P1 requests, locks while executing request(). As soon as your synchronized section ends (i.e. the function ends), you release the lock.
- P1 delays()
- While P1 delays, another process can execute the request() method.
- Now, in the milliseconds it takes for P1's request code to execute, it's likely anything in that interim would have hit the lock that P1 had, and is now waiting.

  - This is seemingly why P4 gets in next (P2 and P3 are waiting on a notification since they hit the lock during that time quantum).

In conclusion, your delay() must be within the synchronized section of code **or** you need to use a monitor at a higher level (or just use reentrant locks/semaphores)

*Extra:*
You might also find [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) helpful.

Comment: there is no such thing like an "atomic primitive" within languages like Java. Some platform-specific languages support those but AFAIK java does not. Your link shows one of the implementations of atomic **objects** - every method call is guaranteed to be either atomic or fully threadsafe.

Comment: Right, they're wrapper objects for primitives in Java.

Comment: No, they arent "wrapper objects for primitives" - please stop making things up, its getting ridiculous now. Look into the source-code of `AtomicBoolean` and be astonished. Atomic objects are something like handler classes for native, so-called "Unsafe" objects which are mapped onto something platform-specific. Nothing is being "wrapped". At all. Sometimes you will find Java primitives which are used to **represent** "Unsafe" object states - but thats about it.

Comment: Updated from primitive to class.

Answer (score 0):

A `synchronized(lock) {...}` block acquires the mutex associated with `lock` upon entering the block, and it *releases* the mutex when it leaves the block.

You can't use `synchronized` to do exactly what you asked, because there's no way to separate acquiring the lock from releasing it.

You could move the synchronization up to a higher level in the code (i.e., always do this):

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            g.request(ID);
            delay();
            g.release();
        }
        delay();
    }
}
```

But if it's a hard requirement to leave the synchronization where it is, then you'll either have to go on using semaphores (which is not a bad idea), or use something similar.

---

You could use `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` instead of using `Semaphore`.  It's a slightly lighter-weight solution to your problem, but maybe not 'lighter enough' to make a difference.

Why do you want to change out the semaphore for something else?